# What is the good way to access one object in different methods

Tags: c#

I have an object person that I'm using in several methods on the front-end. How do I do that best? create new instance every time? or do public? or something else? seems pretty basic question to me.

```
public class Employee
    {
    public void DeleteEmployee(int employeeId)
            {
               ......
            }

    public void UpdateEmployee(int employeeId)
            {
               ......
            }

}
```

and then on the front-end(that's how I do it):

```
protected void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         Employee emp = new Employee();
          emp.DeleteEmployee(empId);
       }
 protected void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         Employee emp = new Employee();
          emp.UpdateEmployee(empId);
       }
```

Comment: Please tell us what you're using this object for

Comment: In the sample code, where is your empId coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is what I would call an Employee Manager.  Two popular ways to do this are to create a seperate EmployeeManager object with static methods to perform the operations, or add the static methods to the Employee object.  There is some debate as to which method is the preferred one.  However, the common thought process is that the Employee instance should not know anything about how it is persisted.  So the results would look like either...

```
EmployeeManager.DeleteEmployee(empId);
```

or...

```
Employee.DeleteEmployee(empId);
```

Comment: You're saying on creating new class employeeManager with the difference that it is going to have static DeleteEmployee, while employee class going to stay the way it is now?

Comment: No.  Both will have the static method.  The difference is mostly just a religious debate.  I prefer to separate out the persistence methods to a different class so that they do not clutter the actual object. But that is purely my preference.

Comment: I would also change the DeleteEmployee method to accept an employee object instead of an id. Just my preference (what if you decide to let people pick the employee by name and then delete them).

Answer (score 1):

Make your methods [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx):

```
public static void DeleteEmployee(int employeeId)
{
    ...
}
```

Call it directly on `Employee`:

```
protected void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Employee.DeleteEmployee(empId);
}
```

Comment: bemused, Why would you do that? Any advantage?

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would say the Employee should not be responsible for creating/updating/deleting itself.  The Data context (or Repository, or whatever) should have that responsibility.

So you'd have something like (off-the-cuff, double check spelling/syntax)

```
EmployeeRepository //Normally Inherits a BaseRepository and/or implements an IRepository<T>
{
    public void Create([some parameters here]) {...}
    public void Delete(Employee employee) {...}
    public Employee Find(Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> predicate) {...}
    //other methods...
}
```

And your code would call

```
static void Main()
{
    EmployeeRepository Employees = new EmployeeRepository();

    Employee bob = Employees.Create("Bob");

    Employee fired = Employees.Find(e => e.Id == whatever);
    Employees.Delete(fired);
}
```